# Ruby performance: define method with define_method or eval

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming, eval

While looking through ActiveSupport source code I've noticed that sometimes `eval` is used in places where `define_method` is enough.

Example: [ActiveSupport: Module.delegate](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L129)

I consider `define_method` more clean and safe way of doing things.
What is the benefits of `eval` over `define_method`? 
Perfomance, memory usage, something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use define_method, the method you're defining [can't accept a block](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/using-define_method-with-blocks-in-ruby-18/).

> It’s pretty well known that because of
>   a deficiency in blocks arguments in
>   Ruby 1.8 Class#define_method cannot
>   define methods that take blocks.

```
def x *args, &block; end  # => works!
define_method(:x) {|*args,&block| } # => SyntaxError: compile error
```

The method being defined requires a block:

```
"def #{prefix}#{method}(*args, &block)" # def customer_name(*args, &block)
```

So define_method can't be used.

Comment: This is not a problem in Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be a very nice article on the subject: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/eval_isnt_quite_pure_evil.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the reason in that particular case, but `define_method` takes a block, which is a closure (carries local variables of the place it was defined), and that can lead to considerably higher memory consumption comparing to plain `eval`.

Comment: I thought that `eval` tended to be the slowest approach.

Comment: Maybe it isn't slower after all, based on the link provided by @emboss.